# vba excel formula in locked cell changes to numeric value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a simple formula (an AutoSum) in a protected sheet and locked cell.  My VBA code does not access this cell directly.  Despite this, the formula sometimes changes to the numeric result when the sum changes.  Any ideas how I can prevent this from happening?

Comment: *the formula sometimes changes to the numeric result when the sum changes.* - you mean that it changes from, for example, `=SUM(A1:A10)` to `50`?

Comment: Yes. Exactly.  I used a set of IsFormula queries at each sheet change and tracked it down to a conditional formatting color change.  Still makes no sense but is fixed. Thank you Scott!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the Cell value is being set implicitly which over writes the formula. You may have a cell reference that you are missing. If your code does not set anything in that cell, then there is something in your workbook doing it. Try going to the Formulas tab and selecting Trace Dependents. See if an arrow points to something you were not aware of. Some of my sheets get so huge that I can loose track of things. Especially if I do any cutting and pasting.